# Why does Word cut off letters in a cell?

Tags: microsoft-word

In the screenshot beneath, the text input is `pypypypypypypypypy`.

This table originates from a document created by someone else and sent to me. I didn't create a new document that began with this cutoff.

[image]

Comment: It looks like the line spacing is too small for the font size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the **Paragraph** dialog and check if `Line Spacing` is set to `Exactly` some point size. Change it to Single or some other value that suits you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If only the ***top*** line of the cell is affected (wrapped lines are ok), changing line spacing won't work.

Select the affected rows, change the row height of all affected rows to "at least" (or untick "specify height"). (Alt_A,R or right click,R)

(This issue seems to arise after row heights are set to "exact" then a row is dragged?)

[image: Set row height to at least]

Single line space did not fix it (nor adding space before paras)

[image: 'Single line space' WRONG]

Actually setting an exact line space can help (but can lead to other problems if "exact" row heights are changed).  You need to find the correct line space by testing.

[image: Set line space helps but doesn't fix]